# fmt:message default value

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Is there a way to output a default value if the  key is not defined?

```
<fmt:message key='some.key' />
```

I expected a `default` attribute to be there, but it is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a resource bundle key does not exist using JSTL tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739170/how-can-i-check-if-a-resource-bundle-key-does-not-exist-using-jstl-tags)

Comment: Is close, but it is not the same. For example my workaround is not applicable to the other question.

Comment: Apparently you're using a custom localization context. The JSTL default returns `???some.key???` when the key is not found. Are you using a framework on top of JSP/Servlet? Perhaps you need to look in that corner for the right solution.

Comment: I really do not have control on that part. Isn't standard for `fmt:message` to output `undef (some.key)` ?

Comment: No, it isn't. What taglib is that `<str:replace>` from, by the way? I don't recognize this from any taglib/framework. Is it homegrown? Perhaps the very same framework has also supplied a custom localization context.

Comment: it is jakarta string lib http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/string-doc/intro.html. Thanks for your help. I will stick to my workaround, since it seems mine is a very particular situation.

Comment: OK thanks for information. Wow that must have been a legacy application which was created before I ever started with Java :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this workaround

```
<str:replace replace="undef (some.key)" with="some default value">
    <fmt:message key='some.key' />
</str:replace>
```

which is not the prettiest, thought.

Answer (score 1):

Using a cue from BalusC above, it's straightforward to check for the known string that is returned when a key is missing.  No need for jakarta string lib.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>

...

<fmt:bundle basename="myBundle">
    <fmt:message key="some.key" var="myVar"/>
</fmt:bundle>
<c:if test = "${pageScope.myVar == '???some.key???'}">
    <c:set var="myVar" value="My Default Value"/>
</c:if>
```